# MIME type for .srt in android

Tags: android, mime-types

I want to access the srt files only but can not do so. I have done with it with `intent.setType("text/plain");` but the problem with this is that it gets all the other text files as well. I have tried `intent.setType("text/srt");` but it doesn't get any file. Is there any way I can get only the srt files using a certain mime type?

Comment: There does not appear to be an official MIME type for SRT files other than `text/plain`. Most likely you will need to stick with `text/plain` and simply validate the input to confirm that it is a valid SRT file.

Answer (score 4):

For Android 10 and above, use `application/x-subrip` and for Android 9 and below use `application/octet-stream` to pick .srt files.

You can set intent type as shown below:

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
          addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
          type = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
                  "application/x-subrip" 
                 else 
                  "application/octet-stream"
}
```